# How to use a package from cturtle in diamondback

Tags: ros, cturtle, ros-diamondback, rospack

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I would like to know how to use a package, say image_view for cturtle in diamondback. I tried to copy and paste in the diamondback, but, too many in dependencies have to resolve.

I guess there will be an elegant way of doing it.

Thanks in advance..

-alfa-

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9118/how-to-use-a-package-from-cturtle-in-diamondback/) by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1053 on 2011-02-17

Post score: -1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mjcarroll](https://answers.ros.org/users/9/mjcarroll/) on 2011-02-21**:
Please don't put [SOLVED] in the title.  Also, don't mark every question as a community wiki, there is no reason for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is generally not possible. Use the Diamondback version of `image_view`.

- There are often packaging and interface changes that affect compatibility between distribution subcomponents.
- The main reason for making distributions is to release a coherent collection of stacks at a common level.
- External interfaces maintain compatibility unless there is some important reason for changing.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2011-02-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

## **Comment by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on 2011-02-20**:
Running "roswtf" gives me "Loaded plugin tf.tfwtf
No package or stack in context

Static checks summary:

Found 1 error(s).

## ERROR PYTHONPATH [/opt/ros/unstable/ros/core/roslib/src:/opt/ros/diamondback/ros/core/roslib/src:] is invalid: Multiple roslib directories in PYTHONPATH (there should only be one)

Beginning tests of your ROS graph. These may take awhile...
analyzing graph...
... done analyzing graph
running graph rules...
... done running graph rules

Online checks summary:

No errors or warnings
"

**Comment by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on 2011-02-20**:
Running"echo $ROS_PACKAGE_PATH" gives "/home/shah/ni/ni:/opt/ros/unstable/stacks" and running "echo $ROS_ROOT" gives "/opt/ros/unstable/ros". How do I change to diamondback because I do not want to use unstable.

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2011-02-20**:
Please post `echo $ROS_PACKAGE_PATH` output, and `echo $ROS_ROOT`.

**Comment by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on 2011-02-18**:
Unfortunately, it didn't work running 'rospack profile'.

**Comment by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) on 2011-02-18**:
Try running 'rospack profile' to update your list of packages known to rospack -- that might help your auto-completion issues.

**Comment by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on 2011-02-18**:
I actually want to use image_view package. It is there, the executable in the  /opt/ros/diamondback/stacks/image_pipeline/image_view/bin directory. In the .../image_view directory, I've already exported the package path using this command: export ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=$PWD:$ROS_PACKAGE_PATH. The problem is that when I run to invoke rosrun in the terminal, it is not auto-completing the image_view or the like, instead, it straightaway gives "rosrun image_transport"..huhu. Any ideas??